# Determine the value of $k$ such that the line determined by the points $(3,2)$ and $(1,-2)$ is tangent to the graph of $y=\frac{k}{x+1}$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have done the following work but I am stuck on solving for k. Am I doing this right? If so what do I do next?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to calculate the straight line?

Comment: do you mean the equation of the straight line?

Comment: Yes. The slope of 2 is right. But the constant is missing.

Comment: I found the equation of the straight line to be y=2(x-3)+2

Comment: I have $y=2x-4$ due the equation $2=3a+b, -2=a+b$ where $y=ax+b$

Comment: Yes, I have the same equation, but mine was not simplified. I'm just confused as to where I go from here?

Comment: You set equal the functions and the slopes: $k/(x+1)=2x-4, -k/(x+1)^2=2$

Comment: wait, why did you include both the function and the derivative of the function? Which one do I set equal to the line?

Comment: You set equal the line $2x-1$ to $y=k/(x+1)$ And additional you set equal the slope of the line (2) equal to the derivative of y which is $-k/(x+1)^2$

Comment: So do I solve for k for both? What do I do then?

Comment: You just have to solve for $k$. But is does not harm if you calculate x as well. If you have found k you have found $y=k/(x+1)$

Comment: I found k=2x^2-2x-4. How do I get the constant k?

Comment: I also got 2x^2 +4x +2 = -k

Comment: I will post an answer to show you the next steps.

Comment: You could also solve this without calculus: the problem is equivalent to finding $k$ such that the line and hyperbola have exactly one intersection.

Comment: But I still don't understand how to get k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$1.$ $k/(x+1)=2x-4$

$2.$  $-k/(x+1)^2=2$

First equation

Multiplying it by $(x+1)$

$k=(x+1)\cdot (2x-4)=2x^2-4x+2x-4=2x^2-2x-4 \quad (1)$

Second equation

Multiply it by $(x+1)^2$

$-k=2(x+1)^2=2x^2+4x+2 \Rightarrow k=-2x^2-4x-2 \quad (2)$

Set $(1)$ equal to $(2)$

$2x^2-2x-4=-2x^2-4x-2$

$4x^2+2x-2=0$

$2x^2+1x-1=0$

Solve for $x$. This gives $x_1=-1$ and $x_2=0.5$

$x_1$ is not in the domain of $y=k/(x+1)$.

Now insert $x=0.5$ in  $k/(x+1)=2x-4$ to obtain the value of $k$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are given a function $$y=\frac{k}{x+1}.$$
The line defined by the two points has a slope of $$m=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\frac{2-(-2)}{3-1}=2$$
and therefore has an equation $$y-2=2(x-3)\Rightarrow2x-y-4=0$$

We want the original function and the tangent line to have exactly one point of intersection (by the definition of a tangent line), so we have the set of equations

\begin{cases} y=\dfrac{k}{x+1} \\ 2x-y-4=0
\end{cases}

Solving by substitution we have
\begin{align}
2x-\frac{k}{x+1}-4&=0\\
2x(x+1)-k-4(x+1)&=0\\
2x^2-2x+(-4-k)&=0
\end{align}

This quadratic equation has exactly one solution when the discriminant $b^2-4ac=0$.  Thus, we have
\begin{align}
b^2-4ac=0&=(-2)^2-4(2)(-4-k)\\
0&=4+32+8k\\
8k&=-36\\
k&=-\frac92
\end{align}

A graph of the two functions:

[image]